# AngularJS to show URL only to the owner

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have 2 blocks: The first div is for the owner of the page and has a link to the logs page. The other div is for the guest users to show the log but not clickable.

```
<!-- for owners -->
<div ui-sref="app.log" ng-show="session.user.name == user.name">
    <div class="center-block">
        {{user.log}}
    </div>
</div>

<!-- for guest users -->
<div ng-show="!session.isLoggedIn">
    <div class="center-block">
        {{user.log}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I have so many of such repeated codes in my file and would like to apply the **ui-sref** only to the owner. How should I do it without having to repeat the div everytime?

Comment: create a directive for the repeating logic.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: There are plenty of examples of how to write a directive already, and your problem is specific enough that an example using your code would be essentially written from scratch.  You asked how you might accomplish this, not for someone to do it for you....

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guide to creating simple directives: 
http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/

You could create a directive that would be as simple as:

```
<my-log my-log-session="session"></my-log>
```

The `my-log-session` attribute allows you to pass variables into the directive.